# Who is the creator of the manga Yu Yu Hakusho?

Tags: yu-yu-hakusho

Yu Yu Hakusho is one of my favorite shows. But unfortunately I don't know the name of the creator of this series. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The original manga was written by Yoshihiro Togashi. He's also the author of Hunter x Hunter, among other less well-known series.

I read an interview in the US Shounen Jump where he talked about how Yu Yu Hakusho began with his idea for a series that would start with the protagonist dying, and how later portions were informed by his love of horror movies such as *Dawn of the Dead*.

He's married to Naoko Takeuchi, the author of the Sailor Moon manga.

[Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoshihiro_Togashihttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoshihiro_Togashi).